# Mobile Safari question editing, doesn't work with long questions (iPad)

Tags: support, iphone, ipad

The questions text area doesn't scroll to show the complete question. Because of the lack of arrow keys, there's also no alternative way to get to the end of the question.

I think the ideal form is to have the text area stretch show it shows all the text.

Comment: The two-finger scroll works for all devices running iPhone OS

Comment: yeah, I figured that out by now, never knew it actually. Lets hope people can find this question and the obvious answer in the future :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can scroll with 2 fingers on the text area.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that one.